# Add text on image using PIL. error message

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code that downloads an image and writes text on the image. The download works fine. The error occurs on the draw.text line. I'm not sure why I am getting an error. The ttf file is in the correct location and pathname is correct. I installed Pillow using pip. I didn't come across any errors with it.

```
import urllib

urlSA = "http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/" + year + "/usfntsfc" + year + month + day + "09.gif"
savedFileSA = "C:/images/sa2000/" + month + day + yearShort + ".jpg"

urllib.urlretrieve (urlSA, savedFileSA)

# Add a title to the SA image
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.open(savedFileSA)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("C:/images/arial.ttf", 12)
draw.text((10, 10),"Sample Text",(3,3,3),font=fnt)

img.save(savedFileSA)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\images\storm_reports_Arc103.py", line 105, in <module>
draw.text((10, 10),"Sample Text",(3,3,3),font=fnt)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 253, in text
ink, fill = self._getink(fill)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 129, in _getink
ink = self.palette.getcolor(ink)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImagePalette.py", line 101, in getcolor
self.palette = [int(x) for x in self.palette]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

Comment: You are saving a `.gif` as a `.jpg`, I imagine that has a lot to do with it.

Comment: I changed it back to save as a .gif but still get the same error. Yes I believe so. The gif image is there in the folder.

Comment: I deleted the "(3,3,3)" code and it worked. Maybe I need to install more colors on my machine or something?

Comment: I deleted it and it worked for me as well, although I was getting different errors from you. GIFs only go up to 256 colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the GIF picture is palettized. If you convert it first to RGB, your code will work.

Change the line

```
img = Image.open(savedFileSA)
```

to

```
img = Image.open(savedFileSA).convert("RGB")
```

Below is the code that works on my machine. It downloads a picture and put a big green 'Sample Text' on it. Note that I'm on OSX, so my paths may differ from yours.

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import urllib

urlSA = "http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/sfc/2015/usfntsfc2015010518.gif"
savedFileSA = "andrew.gif"
urllib.urlretrieve (urlSA, savedFileSA)

img = Image.open(savedFileSA).convert("RGB")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Comic Sans MS.ttf", 72)
draw.text((10, 10), "Sample Text", (0, 128, 0), font=fnt)

img.show()
img.save("andrew.jpg")
```